# How to send String from Python sever to Kotlin client

Tags: python, android, sockets, kotlin

The server is Python and the client is Kotlin. When I send String from the server, String is printed from the client.
The simple code is here, but the client doesn't print it.
What could be the problem?

Server code

```
# server.py 

import socket

from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread

host = '192.168.0.22' 
port = 5000            

server_sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET)
server_sock.bind((host, port))
server_sock.listen(1)

client_sock, addr = server_sock.accept()
print('Connected by', addr)
data="1234567"
client_sock.send(data.encode())


client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
```

Client code

```
package com.cfsuman.client

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import java.io.DataInputStream
import java.net.Socket


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val thread = Thread(Runnable {
            var socket = Socket("192.168.0.22", 5000)
            var input = socket.getInputStream()
            var dis = DataInputStream(input)

            var data_input = dis.read()
            println(data_input)

            socket.close()
        }).start()
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the two devices on the same network?

Comment: Yes. They are on the same network.